# How to change the value of the currently selected item in the list box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox

I know one can get the value of the currently selected item like this:

`var myListBoxItemText = $('#myListBox').val().toString();`

But how do you change this value in the list box to something else?

Comment: You usually don't need `toString()`. As far as I'm concerned there aren't any elements returning a non-string value.

Comment: @pimvdb: Yeah I'm just never sure because I've had some nasty bugs due to clashing types and am never sure what type is returned from a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your update in the comments, here's an updated answer. Just use the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to filter the options inside of your `select` element to get the selected option.

To change a `select` element's selected option's `value` property:

```
 $('#myListBox option:selected').val('new value');
```

To change its display text:

```
 $('#myListBox option:selected').text('new text');
```

***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/NubSF/)***

Comment: Yes, you asked for the value, but I thought you meant the text, so I included both. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$("#myListBox").val("This is the new value");`

Although, by 'listbox', I assume you mean a `select` element. In which case you'll have to add the property `selected` to one of the child `option` elements.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that and it didn't work which led me to ask this question. I'll try again

Comment: Yeah I mean a select element sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myListBox').val(your_val);
```

Here your_val denotes the `value` attribute of `<option>`

Or you can also use

```
$('#myListBox')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

or

```
  $('#myListBox').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/175/)**

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/176/)**

Comment: instead of `[0]` you can use `.prop('selectedIndex', 1)` as well, if you need the jQuery object returned for further chaining.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I guess I wasn't clear enough. I do not want to change the selection index. I actually want to *change the value* in the currently selected item. Like, if the currently selected item is 'Apple', I want the code to change the text from 'Apple' to 'Banana'.

Comment: @RyanPeschel `selectedIndex` will also change the value, see DEMO 2