# how to replace value in listbox in java script

Tags: javascript

Replace value in listbox in java script...

```
<select id="list" >
    <option value="1">Null value</option>

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>
```

so in the first option NUll value is present how to remove or replace with any text in javascript???

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939731/how-to-change-the-value-of-the-currently-selected-item-in-the-list-box

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-to-change-html-selected-option-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be following will help you...

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjabu)

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("list").options[0]=new Option("New Text", "newval", true, false)
```

If you want to change Null value present at any location, you can try following.

```
var options = document.getElementById("list").options;
for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++) {
  if(options[i].innerHTML == "Null value") {
    document.getElementById("list").options[i]=new Option("New Text", "newval", false, false)
  }
}
```

Comment: it work fine but i am having lot value so i cant able to find position of it so its possible to change value like if(document.getElementById("list").value=="Null value"){change to some text like }

Comment: wat do you mean by value ? do you want to change internal value of each option or text(that is displayed in dropdown) ?

Comment: i thought u have misunderstood the thing is am having 100 value in list box with one "NULL VALUE" so i cant able to find it position of index ...how to change dynamically it...??? not multi "NULL VALUE"

Comment: to find its position, you'll need to iterate through all of the options. In this case also, above code should work.

Comment: another doubt i.e if (null value ) is present in listbox is its possible to remove the value...

Comment: ys, you can do something like `if(options[i].innerHTML == "Null value") {
    options[i]=null;
  }`

Comment: is there any syntax like this...document.getElementById("Geography").options[i].remove;

Answer (score 1):

You should give an ID to the box first to access it via JavaScript. Then you could use a button that changes the innerHTML  of the ID by clicking on it (maybe you want to use JQuery but it's your choice).

Here's an example:

```
<select id="list" >
<option id="firstOption" value="1">Null value</option>

<option value="1">item 1</option>

<option value="2">item 2</option>

<option value="3">item 3</option>

<option value="4">item 4</option>

<option value="0">All</option>

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('firstOption').innerHTML='Changed';"/>
```

You can also access the element by it's class but as soon as you add more options it will cause problems.

Comment: i am having lot value so i cant able to find position of it so its possible to change value like if(document.getElementById("list").value=="Null value"){change to some text like }

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js) to loop through elements and find any 'Null value' ones and replace them with whatever you need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // loop through all options in a list
  $('#list').find('option').each(function (index) {
    // if text is what you need
    if ($(this).text() == 'Null value')
        // replace it 
        $(this).text('Whatever')
  });
});
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/GuWtD/

This works even if **Null value** is not the first and is multiple in list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/25MVf/

```
<select id="list" >
    <option value="1">Null value</option>

    <option value="1">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>

<div id='change'>Change Value</div>


var chg = document.getElementById('change');
chg.onclick = function () {
    var slt = document.getElementById('list');
    slt.children[0].text = "Value Changed";
}
```